# Split a string by semicolons on new line in c#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I'm `generating string dynamically` and `passed to method for further execution`.

I want every string after `;(semicoln)` on new line because `;(semicolon)` is the character i'm unable to parse.

```
 string myCode = "MyClient client = new MyClient();
 var result = Task.Run(() => 
 client.For<Customer>().FindEntriesAsync()).Result.AsEnumerable<Customer>();
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);";
```

Right now I managed above string like below but how to do it in a single code like when input is above string ?

```
 string myCode = "MyClient client = new MyClient();";
 myCode += Environment.NewLine + "var result = Task.Run(() => 
 client.For<Customer>().FindEntriesAsync()).Result.AsEnumerable<Customer>();";
 myCode += Environment.NewLine + "return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);";
```

Comment: What do you mean "because `;` is the character i'm unable to parse."?

Comment: I can see how weston's answer could apply here, but I'm confused by "generating string dynamically". That doesn't look like what you're doing - especially if weston's answer is correct. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The code here in question is dummy , I actually generating string in text file and replaced generated string on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, text.Split(';'));
```

Answer (score 6):

A prefix of `@` allows newlines in-line:

```
 string myCode = @"MyClient client = new MyClient();
 var result = Task.Run(() => client.For<Customer>().FindEntriesAsync()).Result.AsEnumerable<Customer>();
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);";
```

And it even works with Stackoverflow syntax highlighting, how nice.